# REACT JS mandatory field check before form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to develop a react form with multiple fields are marked as mandatory without which form should not be submitted.

What are the easiest way to do this? Is there are props for each field level by which I can apply check before submission? Or any other easy way? Please help

Comment: On form Submit callback. Add event.preventDefault(). Do your validations and then submit form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you are looking for. You could do something like this, it might be the easiet way.

But you might want some validation for your form - checkout yup on npmjs.com

```
<input type="text" required/>
```

Comment: What I am looking for, without any validation code even we use "required" keyword, the REACT form is getting submitted. So, what is the code I can use to check whether mandatory field has been filled up before form gets submitted.